# Function not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm a newbie of javascript and I was triying to add a method to the object prototype (just for educational reasons) but for some reason it doesn't work on IE8, the debugger says: "the object doesn't support this method or property"(hardly translation from the spanish version of IE)

here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="x">hello</p>
        <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("x");

        Object.prototype.addEvent = function(a, b)
                        {   
                            if(document.addEventListener)
                            {
                            this.addEventListener(a, b);
                            }
                            else if(document.attachEvent)
                            {
                            this.attachEvent("on" + a, b);
                            }
                        }
        x.addEvent("click", function()
        {
        alert("hello");
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Without sounding too sly, **most** things a web developer does won't work on Internet Explorer.

Comment: hahaha just as I said I'm new on this thing and I didn't get why all web developers hate IE, now I get it hahaha. But in this case I'm using the "attachEvent" function so the event should work in IE8

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate. [Here's an answer regarding IE DOM elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4210948/2719528)

Comment: You'll need to extend `HTMLElement.prototype` instead. Should work in all browsers except IE6/7, which shouldn't matter.

Comment: @squint If only that were always true...

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda: You mean IE 6/7? I think it's true for most at this point but if support is needed, then yeah, extending host prototypes is  out.

Comment: @squint nope, it doesn't work. it says: "HTMLElement" is not defined (translation from spanish to english of IE)

Comment: Sorry, in IE8 you need `Element.prototype`.

Comment: @squint thanks, dude! you're awesome. I'm getting prepared for all the headaches that IE gives to all web developers in earth.

Comment: @JoseLuis: There are IE8 polyfills that you can use to smooth out just about everything. You can set it up so that the code is only downloaded when the browser is IE8.